# How to add -options to my alias/ function

Tags: terminal, zsh

I have this function that creates directory with the current date + user input as the name

```
alias mkdirDate="f1"
function f1() {
        export tmp=""
        vared -p 'Project name: ' -c tmp
        mkdir "$(date +%Y%m%d) $tmp"
        fi
}
```

id like to add the possibility to use options like in `rm` or `find` to add functionality.

is there any other way OTHER than something like `if [ $tmp='-p' ] touch file.py` ?

Comment: zsh comes with `getopts` that you can use for this; see `zshbuiltins(1)`. For just some basic boolean options just looping over `$argv` would probably be simpler though. Also, you don't need `alias mkdirDate="f1"`, just name the function `mkdirDate` and it will work if you type `mkdirDate` in your shell.

Comment: Thanks, i will look into it. And while you are right i still like it to have to as an alias, this way when i look into my aliases i don't forget about its existence.

Comment: First define the synopsis, i.e. write a specification, how exactly your function should be invoked. After this, it makes sense to discuss how to implement it. For me, I usually use `zparseopts` for option parsing with zsh, but without knowing, how your call interface is supposed to look like, I can't tell you whether there isn't a better way for your case.